# Can't receive NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic in URLSessionDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, basic-authentication, credentials, urlsession

I'm trying to realise basic-authentication using `URLSessionDelegate` and `URLCredentials`

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void)
```

Apple recommends not to write manually `Authorization` header. So I'm trying to use `URLCredentials`.

I'm doing very simple example in Swift Playground:

```
class Callback: NSObject {}

extension Callback: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void) {
        print("received challenge")
        print(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}

let callback = Callback()
var configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: callback, delegateQueue: nil)

let string = "http://demo0230490.mockable.io/test"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: string)!)
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print("response")
    print(response)
}.resume()

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

The problem is – **I don't receive auth challenge**.

If you go to `http://demo0230490.mockable.io/test` in browser you will see the browser showing alert for basic auth.
From my mock http I return header like:

```
"Www-Authenticate" =     (
        "Basic realm=\"Access to MRM\""
    );
```

Also I tried switching to `https` (I mean `https://demo0230490.mockable.io/test`) to check whether I'll receive auth challenge of type `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`. 
And that works. That means that my `delegate` is properly set and works in some circumstances.

**So the question is**:
Can anybody point the problem or provide the working example for basic auth using `URLCredentials` (for example using https://www.mockable.io)?

Comment: If I remember correctly you can't use delegate with Closure/Block in URLSession, it's either the one or the other, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1409308-urlsession) `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)` is called only in two situations:

> - When a remote server asks for client certificates or Windows NT LAN Manager (NTLM) authentication, to allow your app to provide
>     appropriate credentials
> - When a session first establishes a connection to a remote server that uses SSL or TLS, to allow your app to verify the server’s
>     certificate chain

When you are switching to https the second condition is met and therefore method is called.

There is two types of authentication challenges: session-level and non-session-level. 
For non-session-level challenges URLSession calls `urlSession(_:task:didReceive:completionHandler:)`. For session-level challenges URLSession calls `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)`.

Difference between session-level challenges and  non-session-level challenges is described in the discussion section of `urlSession(_:task:didReceive:completionHandler:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession):

> - For session-level challenges—NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM, NSURLAuthenticationMethodNegotiate,
>     NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate, or
>     NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust—the NSURLSession object calls the
>     session delegate’s urlSession(*:didReceive:completionHandler:) method.
>     If your app does not provide a session delegate method, the
>     NSURLSession object calls the task delegate’s
>     urlSession(*:task:didReceive:completionHandler:) method to handle the
>     challenge.
> - For non-session-level challenges (all others), the URLSession object calls the session delegate’s
>     urlSession(*:task:didReceive:completionHandler:) method to handle the
>     challenge. If your app provides a session delegate and you need to
>     handle authentication, then you must either handle the authentication
>     at the task level or provide a task-level handler that calls the
>     per-session handler explicitly. The session delegate’s
>     urlSession(*:didReceive:completionHandler:) method is not called for
>     non-session-level challenges.

In your case you should implement non-session-level challenge handler:

```
extension Callback: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        print("received task challenge")
    }
}
```

Also there is working example on [Apple-forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68809).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `urlSession(_:task:didReceive:completionHandler:)` of `URLSessionTaskDelegate`. Method you use is for connection-level challenge, not for app-level.